# GIF images to UIImageView using AlamofireImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, gif, alamofireimage

I am using AlamofireImage library to download/cache web images and show it in UIImageView inside tableViewCells.

```
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil, imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.3), runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: { (response) in
//...... other code .....
})
```

It works perfect for .png/.jpg or other still images but I am not able to show GIF images using this.

I tried using external library to convert imageData to gif images and it works perfect however Alamofire is not caching the gif data and next time the image loads as still image.

Check the code below:

```
imageView.af_setImage(withURL: url, placeholderImage: nil, filter: nil, imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.3), runImageTransitionIfCached: true, completion: { (response) in

        if imageUrl.hasSuffix("gif") {
            if let data = response.data{
                self.imageView.image = UIImage.gifImageWithData(data)
            }
        }
    })
```

The above code shows the GIF for first time but next time only still image appears.

Any idea how the following can be achieved using AlamofireImage:

1. Download the GIF imageData for the first time, cache it and show GIF to imageView
2. Next time get the imageData from cache and show GIF again

Comment: for this use SDWebImage library. which is best in caching too.

Comment: Any chance this can be done with AlamofireImage? I don't want to add another library to the project for same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a direct way to play GIF with AlamofireImage but we can do using **SwiftyGif**. I'm using AlamofireImage throughout the app but for display GIF and load from the server, I'm using SwiftyGif. Using SwiftyGif you can play, load from the server as well as locally. I think it will be reliable solution instead of use SDWebImage.

[SwiftyGif](https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif)

```
// You can also set it with an URL pointing to your gif
let url = URL(string: "...")
let loader = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .white)
cell.gifImageView.setGifFromURL(url, customLoader: loader)
```

Answer (score -2):

- Download GIF file , next time get the file and show

  ```
  Alamofire.download(gifUrl, to: destination).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
      response in

      if let filePath = response.destinationURL?.path{
          if let gifImage = UIImage.init(contentsOfFile: filePath){
              self.imageVIew.image = gifImage
          }
      }
  })
  ```